# Physical implementation of gates on IBM Q

Tags: quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience, experimental-realization

There is a lot of quantum gates in IBM Q Composer, however, only few are implemented physically while others can be composed of them.

When one looks at description of a quantum processor in IBM Q interface, there is a list of *basis gates*. For example those are `id, u1, u2, u3, cx` for Melbourne processor. However, gates $I$, $U1$ and $U2$ are special cases of $U3$. If one removes statement `include "qelib1.inc";` from QASM code, only $CNOT$ and $U3$ gates are left. So, it seems that all single qubit gates are implemented with $U3$ and there is of course two qubits $CNOT$.

According to IBM Q manual, $U3$ gate is implemented by *three frame changes and two $X_{\pi/2}$ pulses*.

**My questions are these:**

1. Which gates are implemented physically on IBM Q? I would expect $CNOT$ and some single qubit gates but which ones?
2. What are *frame changes* and *$X_{\pi/2}$ pulses* used for gate implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.03719.pdf) they talk primarily about **ibmqx4**.

> The gates listed in Eq. (26) are provided by IBM for the user’s convenience. However these are
> not the gates that are physically implemented by their quantum computer. IBM has a compiler that
> translates the gates in (26) into products of gates from a physical gate set. The physical gate set
> employed by IBM is essentially composed of three gates [1]:
> {U1(λ), RX (π/2), CNOT} .

It seems that the link [1] from the paper is broken but I was able to find [this](https://github.com/Qiskit/ibmq-device-information/tree/master/backends/rueschlikon/V1), which is device information of *IBM Q 16 Rueschlikon* **ibmxq5** (formerly ibmqx3)
They mention:

> A frame change (FC) is equivalent to applying a virtual Z-gate in software, where Z(θ)=FC(-θ). Gaussian derivative (GD) and Gaussian flattop (GF) pulses are defined with amplitude and angle parameters.

[image]

**Summary:**

1. I believe in the IBM Q Experience platform, the term "basis gates",
   which you can find in each backend's specification, refers to the
   implemented physical gates on that specific device.
    So for Melbourne we'll have `id, u1, u2, u3, cx`.
    *This should be confirmed by someone from IBM Q team though, but I think physical gates, native gates and basis gates are interchangeable terms.*
2. The above image should explain your second question.