# What is the executable opcode for Qiskit quantum hardware, as the quantum circuits or the transpiled/compiled QObj/ QASMQObj are assembly languages?

Tags: qiskit, programming, architecture, experimental-realization, qasm

When we write a QASM code or build quantum circuit on Qiskit GUI, it converts it into QObj/QASMQObj (refering paper [Qiskit Backend Specifications for OpenQASM and OpenPulse Experiments](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.03452.pdf)) or its transpiled version, before executing. However this is assembly language, how it is converted into opcode/bytecode before executing on the hardware?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Physical implementation of gates on IBM Q](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/10212/physical-implementation-of-gates-on-ibm-q)