# What are the possible gates that I can use to vary input states before CNOT?

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, entanglement, noise

We know that the noise of the $\text{CNOT}$ gate varies depending on the input state before it.

**What are the gates that I can put in the place of the 4 identity gates above to change the input state that goes to $\text{CNOT}$?** [image]
For example, if I just place a Hadamard gate then $|+\rangle$ state is the input to $\text{CNOT}$ and this might be noisier than other states. What are the possible gates that I can put before $\text{CNOT}$ to vary the input state?
I know that $S$, $T$, $S^\dagger$, $T^\dagger$, $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ gates do not change the $|+\rangle$ state if I put them. and if I use a general `u3` gate then Qiskit divides it into multiple gate operations and that can be even noisier to start with.

Comment: First I need to say that $\hat Z|+\rangle=|-\rangle$. Then, your question is about analyzing the noise of a quantum operation, but what your further statement shows is quite different from that. Qiskit has a particular package when dealing with the noisy, `Qiskit Ignis`.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what you have mentioned in the question, when you use a $u_3$ gate, Qiskit does not break it up into multiple gates. In fact $u_3$ gate is one of the basis gates for all Qiskit backends and all the single qubit gates are ultimately implemented as $u_1, u_2$ or $u_3$ gates (You can check more about those gates [here](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-states/single-qubit-gates.html#7.-General-U-gates--)). Since $u_3$ gate is the most generalized single qubit gate, using $u_3$ gates in place of the $I$ gates will give you more freedom to vary you input to the $CNOT$ gate.

Comment: I think you confuse $u_3$ with $u_1$. Look at the following post: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/10212/physical-implementation-of-gates-on-ibm-q