# What is the basic hardware gate library in the IBM & google?

Tags: ibm-q-experience, google-sycamore

I need to know what is the basic hardware gate library in hardware IBM and Google? I mean, which one of the gates can be implemented directly in the hardware. I would be very grateful if everyone helps me.

Comment: This may help https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/10212/physical-implementation-of-gates-on-ibm-q

Comment: Thanks very much, what about physical gates in Google? and another question is which so Hadamard gate is not a physical gate? if so, what is the similar gate with Hadamard in the physical layer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### IBM

You can view the basis gates that supporting at the hardware level for IBM's hardware through your dashboard. All the devices with more than 1 qubit have the same set of basis gates $\{CX, ID, RZ, SX, X \}$. Below is a screenshot of a particular device named *ibmq_bogota*.

[image: Bogota]

---

### Google

From google's [quantum computer datasheet](https://quantumai.google/hardware/datasheet/weber.pdf) and [Cirq documentation here](https://quantumai.google/cirq/google/devices) it seems like the google devices implement the following set of gates:

**One qubit gate:** $U3$ (general one-qubit gates pf any rotation), $X, Y, Z$.

**Two qubit gates:**  Sycamore gate, which has the matrix representation as $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -i & 0 \\ 0 & -i & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{-i\pi/8} \end{pmatrix}$

The $\sqrt{iSWAP}$ gate which has the matrix representation as $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Other two qubit gate that being supported is the $CZ$ gate.

---

### IonQ

The gates supported by the IonQ device are:

One qubit gates: $ GPI(\phi) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & e^{-i\phi} \\ e^{i\phi} & 0\end{pmatrix}, GPI2(\phi) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -ie^{-i\phi} \\ -ie^{i\phi} & 1\end{pmatrix}, GZ(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix}  e^{-i\theta/2} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\theta/2}  \end{pmatrix} $

Two qubit gates:
The [Mølmer-Sørenson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B8lmer%E2%80%93S%C3%B8rensen_gate) gate (MS): $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & -i\\ 0 & 1 & -i & 0\\ 0 & -i & 1 & 0\\ -i & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

[See this documentation by IonQ](https://ionq.com/best-practices) for more details.